# Is there something like Python's getattr() in C#?

Tags: c#, python, user-interface

Is there something like [Python's getattr()](https://web.archive.org/web/20200703234823/http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm) in C#? I would like to create a window by reading a list which contains the names of controls to put on the window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is also [Type.InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx).

```
public static class ReflectionExt
{
    public static object GetAttr(this object obj, string name)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                 BindingFlags.Public | 
                                 BindingFlags.GetProperty;

        return type.InvokeMember(name, flags, Type.DefaultBinder, obj, null);
    }
}
```

Which could be used like:

```
object value = ReflectionExt.GetAttr(obj, "PropertyName");
```

or (as an extension method):

```
object value = obj.GetAttr("PropertyName");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use reflection for this.

[`Type.GetProperty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) and [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) each return [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) instances, which can be used to read a property value on an object.

```
var result = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Year").GetValue(dt, null)
```

[`Type.GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) and [`Type.GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx) each return [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) instances, which can be used to execute a method on an object.

```
var result = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToLongDateString").Invoke(dt, null);
```

If you don't necessarily know the type (which would be a little wierd if you new the property name), than you could do something like this as well.

```
var result = dt.GetType().GetProperty("Year").Invoke(dt, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this...

```
typeof(YourObjectType).GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(instanceObjectToGetPropFrom, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the System.Reflection.PropertyInfo class that can be created using object.GetType().GetProperties(). That can be used to probe an object's properties using strings. (Similar methods exist for object methods, fields, etc.)

I don't think that will help you accomplish your goals though. You should probably just create and manipulate the objects directly. Controls have a Name property that you can set, for example.