# compare different type of list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

i have two list one is string list and other one is list of one class.that class contain some properties like soid,itemname,qty etc and its value also..string list and class list have some common property   .so i wanted to check the string list with class list and add common values to one dictionary.

```
public class Input
   {
       public string soid { get; set; }

       public string itemname { get; set; }

       public int qty { get; set; }
   }
list<Input> inputclass=new  list<Input>();//inputclass list

List<string> metadata=new List<string>();//string list
metadata.Add("itemname");
        metadata.Add("soid");
        metadata.Add("qty");
```

so i wanted to compare the class member name with string list name

Comment: And how do you want the dictionary to look? Ie what will be the key, what the value?

Comment: And ? What is your question ? what did you try and which errors did you get ?

Comment: What is the use of `inputclass` here?

Comment: @henk class member name and list<string> will equal.so key either class member name or string and value from list<input> member value.

Comment: @nixen09 I think you should make your Q more clear. For `soid` key, what values do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you want to compare the type itself, not the instances inside that list.

You could do it this way:

```
List<string> metadata = new List<string>();//string list
metadata.Add("itemname");
metadata.Add("soid");
metadata.Add("qty");
metadata.Add("yada");

var result = from str in metadata
             join prop in typeof(Input).GetProperties() on str equals prop.Name
             select str;

foreach (string prop in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop);
}
```

Now, if you have a List of `T` unknown objects and want to match each with the metadata, tell me and I'll help you.

**EDIT** based on your comment: `when we get the common name between list<input> and string how will get the value of corresponding member of the class.now you return only common names r8..?`

You could do it like this. Suppose you have these two classes:

```
public class Input
{
    public string soid { get; set; }

    public string itemname { get; set; }

    public int qty { get; set; }
}

public class Yada : Input
{
    public string yada { get; set; }
}
```

So `Input` has 3 of the 4 properties, and `Yada` class has all 4.

Then suppose we have a list of objects:

```
List<Input> inputclass = new List<Input>();//inputclass list

inputclass.Add(new Input() { itemname = "test",soid="myId",qty=10 });
inputclass.Add(new Yada() { itemname = "test2",soid="myId2", yada = "woo",qty=20 });
```

You could get all the matching properties from the objects, including their current values, with this code:

```
var result = inputclass.Select(
                 input => (from str in metadata
                           join prop in input.GetType().GetProperties()
                           on str equals prop.Name
                           select new { Obj = input, Prop = str, Value = prop.GetValue(input, null) }))
                           .SelectMany(i => i)
                           .GroupBy(obj => obj.Obj);

foreach (var obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
    foreach (var prop in obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Prop + ":" + prop.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
 }

 Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is my input:

[image]

Just on a note, be careful when using `GetValue`: you'll have to do slight changes for it to work with Indexers, for example.

Comment: when we get the common name between list<input> and string how will get the value of corresponding member of the class.now you return only common names r8..?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood you 100% correctly, but given the following input:

```
var inputclass= new List<Input>() {
    new Input(){ soid="123", itemname="Bar", qty=123 },
    new Input(){ soid="777", itemname="Foo", qty=999 } 
};
List<string> metadata=new List<string>() { "itemname", "soid", "qty" };
```

you can use the `.ToDictionary()` and `.GetProperty()` methods like this

```
Type t = typeof(Input);
var result = metadata.ToDictionary(i => i, i => inputclass.Select(c => t.GetProperty(i).GetValue(c)));
```

to create a dictionary that will look like

[image]

**EDIT:**

If `metadata` can contain values that are not properties of `Input`, the following would be save:

```
var result = metadata.Select(i => t.GetProperty(i))
                     .Where(i => i != null)
                     .ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => inputclass.Select(c => i.GetValue(c)));
```

Comment: +1 Great answer. But don't forget the filtering phase. I means what if `i` was not a property of t?

Comment: @domanic i got one error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type .

Comment: @domanic the list<input> contain only one set of value.so you will get only unique result.but i don't know y its giving above error.

Comment: @DominicKexel I'm interested to know what is that tool you are using to show the `Dictionary`?

Comment: @nixen09 so the list `inputclass` always contains a single element? In this case, you can use `inputclass.Select(c => i.GetValue(c)).Single()` to create a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [ReflectionExt.GetAttr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138045/is-there-something-like-pythons-getattr-in-c) you can do something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach(var listItem in inputclass)
{
   foreach(var metaItem in metadata)
   {
       try
       {
            var value = ReflectionExt.GetAttr(listItem, metaItem);

            if (dict[metaItem] == null)
                dict[metaItem] = new List<string>();

            if (!dict[metaItem].Contains(value)) // Add only if not exists
                dict[metaItem].Add(value);
       }
       catch
       {
           ;
       }

   }

}
```