# Array looping C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

from db i am grabbing new list for every insert in db...so i have n number of list and i want only to take first element of it using loops in c#.........

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class UserFirst
    {
        public string UserP(string[]A,string []B,string[]C)
        {          
            string x="";            
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Count(); i++)
            {
                string aElement = A[i];
                string bElement = B[i];
                string cElement = C[i];
                x = aElement + bElement + cElement;
            }            
            return x;
        }
    }
string[] A = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };
string[] B = { "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH" };
string[] C = { "II", "JJ", "KK", "LL" };

UserFirst honey = new UserFirst();            
Console.Write(honey.UserP(A,B,C));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The only reason you would want to do this is if your code/classes were badly designed in the first place.

Comment: up to now I have a vague feeling of knowing what you might try to say. Could you please put a little more effort in the description of what this code is supposed to do?=! ".i want to take first element of arrays eg.a[0] using loops from all three array" is not very clear. Are you trying to combine the 3 arrays into 1? and the 3 elements should be connected by a `,` ?

Comment: new to c# not used with new syntax....................help.....c# there is no getattr function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there something like Python's getattr() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138045/is-there-something-like-pythons-getattr-in-c)

Comment: @Sinatr The problem is: if you're having to resort to Reflection to do what you want to do, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: "there is no getattr function" this might be horrible for you. But it is not really helpful for us. A description of what this function does is helpful. Much more helpful is a description of what you actually want to achieve. Do you know what you want to do? If Yes can you try to describe it a little more in detail?

Comment: You can do what you want without resorting to reflection, by using a `Dictionary`. See [this example](https://ideone.com/U59jIM).

Comment: Thanks to all ...............i am in learning phase ...so thanks for support and guide...............phylogenesis helped verywell.......

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming that all three arrays have the same size, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{
    string aElement = A[i];
    string bElement = B[i];
    string cElement = C[i];
}
```

Comment: there is any replacement for getattr function in c#???????

Comment: @dhiyash2008 do you really expect everyone who knows C# to know what the "getattr" function does ????????? or do you expect us to research first what it actually does just so we would be able to help you????????? It would be adviseable to make the life of people who try to help yiou for free as easy as possible.....

Comment: So? What does it do? I don't speak Python very well. It seems like it takes the object, gets a property by string value (that's why you loop through `"abc"` - to get the property name) and appends the property value to another property x. So I guess you can transform this to `self.x.append(a[0]), self.x.append(b[0]), self.x.append(c[0])`.

Comment: from db i am grabbing new list for every insert in db...so i have n number of list and i want only to take first element of it using loops in c#

Comment: @dhiyash2008 "i want only to take first element", so why do you need a loop then?