# Create Qualified Class Name using Strings

Tags: c#, census

Coming from a Python heavy background, I'm trying to recreate a logic path in C#. The idea is as follows:

```
            string[] items =
            {
                "CensusBlocks",
                "_111thCongressionalDistricts",
                "CensusTracts",
                "Counties",
                "StateLegislativeDistrictsLower",
                "StateLegislativeDistrictsUpper",
                "CountySubdivisions",
                "States"
            };

            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                censusreturn.item.Name = records.result.addressMatches[0].geographies.item[0].BLOCK;
            }
```

Is there a way to use "item" to build the qualified class name as well as new property field? I've been looking into reflection, but that doesn't seem to be yielding what I'm looking for since I already know the types/names of each nested class.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create member names? You might want to check out dynamic and ExpandoObject

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/138045/14160477